# Selenium webdriver : find element question

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, css-selectors, web-inspector

I am trying to use python Selenium for the first time.
This would be a simple question for some of you but I am a bit disappointed here..

I would click on a  link text which will open another webpage (WebDriver IE)

When I inspect the link I have this:

```
<li class="limarginSP"><a class="spLink ng-binding" href="" ng-click="utility.ngPostForm(trans)">Finance System</a></li>
```

I tried this :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path="IEDriverServer.exe")
#local web site
driver.get("http://path.net") 
t = 5
time.sleep(t)
elem_pyFinSys= driver.find_element_by_link_text("Finance System")
elem_pyFinSys.click()
```

but this will open another link in my page
inspection of the link opened below

```
<a class="navLink ng-binding" href="" ng-click="utility.ngPostForm(supp)">Reporting Subscription</a>
```

My question  is how to get the right element  to open the right page? I have to use Internet explorer as the application won't work with other browser.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where exactly is that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use one of the following locators:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("limarginSP>.spLink.ng-binding")
```

Or

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".limarginSP")
```

`find_element_by_link_text` is not always a good idea because there may be many same locators.

Comment: Hi Vitalis,
Big thanks!
I got an error with 
`elem_pyFinSys = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("limarginSP>.spLink.ng-binding")` 
But with
`elem_pyFinSys = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".limarginSP")` 

This works perfectly !!!

Thanks